# .net mvc declare a property to hold a collection of generic objects?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, widget

I have an MVC proyect using EF (database first) and I have already created CRUD for some entities.
Now I am trying to create a dashboard page that contains widgets or similar, each listing the last 10 entities from different db tables (last 10 products created, last 10 customers, etc)
To create the widget I have followed this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/598383/Widgets-in-MVC

So I have 2 interfaces and 2 classes that implements those interfaces:

```
public interface IWidget
{
    int SortOrder { get; set; }
    string Entity { get; set; }
    string CssClassName { get; set; }
    string HeaderText { get; set; }
    string FooterText { get; set; }
    ISubWidget SubWidget { get; set; }
}

public interface ISubWidget
{
    ICollection<Products> EntitiesList { get; set; }
}


public class Widget : IWidget
{
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string Entity { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    public string FooterText { get; set; }
    public ISubWidget SubWidget { get; set; }
}

public class SubWidget : ISubWidget
{
    public ICollection<Products> EntitiesList { get; set; }
}
```

then I have 3 partial views: one for the widget itself, one for the subwidget, and one that will act as a container of all created widgets.

```
@model  Proyect.Comun.Widget.IWidget
<div class="widget">
    <div class="@Model.CssClassName">
        <div class="widgetHeader">
            @Model.HeaderText
        </div>
        <div class="widgetBody">
            @Html.Partial(string.Concat(new[] { "Widget", "/", "_SubWidget" }), @Model.SubWidget)
        </div>
        <div class="widgetFooter">
            @Model.FooterText
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@model  Proyect.Comun.Widget.ISubWidget
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.EntitiesList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product_number) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product_name) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product_description) </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


@model  Fruterias.Comun.Widget.IWidget
@foreach (Proyect.Comun.Widget.IWidget wm in ViewBag.Widgets)
{
    @Html.Partial(string.Concat(new[] { "Widget", "/", "_Widget" }), wm)
}
```

then in the Dashboard controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Widgets = GetWidgetData();
    return View();
}


public List<IWidget> GetWidgetData()
{
    var lastWidget = new List<IWidget>{
        new Widget()
        {
            SortOrder = 1,
            CssClassName = "high",
            Entity = "Products",
            HeaderText = "Last Products",
            FooterText = "",
            SubWidget = new SubWidget {
                EntitiesList = db.products.OrderByDescending(p => p.date).Take(10).ToList(),
            }
        },
    };
    return lastWidget;
}
```

And finally in the view for Dashboard/Index:

```
<p>
    @{
        @Html.Partial("Widget/_WidgetContainer");
    }
</p>
```

This works ok and shows a list of Product entities. But now I want to create different widgets associated to different entities. 
Of course the problem is that the property EntitiesList is declared as a collection of Product objects, so I can not fill it with, for example, customers objects.

What would be the solution here? I could create different interfaces (and classes) for each type of entity, but Im sure there must be a better way...

Also, as the entities models (Products, Customers...) are generated with Entity Framework db first, I guess I can not create an Interface and make them implement that interface (or can I?)... (anytime the db changes and models are regenerated by EF, all that would be lost?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to have the EntitiesList to be a specific type you could just have the SubWidget be generic and set its type when you instantiate.

```
public class SubWidget<T> : ISubWidget<T> where T : class
{
    public ICollection<T> EntitiesList { get; set; }
}
```

or you could use dynamic object.

```
public class SubWidget : ISubWidget
{
    public ICollection<dynamic> EntitiesList { get; set; }
}
```